# Remove symbol from lib file on windows

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, linker

A symbol happens to be defined in two third party libraries, namely, in my case, zlib somehow got its copyright string into both.

I checked this copyright string, and it is a harmless global static string with the copyright notice.

However, I can't link due to this.

Is there an easy way to remove it in one of those libraries?

This is the error:

```
zlib_mdd.lib(deflate.obj) : error LNK2005: _deflate_copyright already defined in libboost_zlib-vc110-mt-gd-1_50.lib(deflate.obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat dirty but effective method is by modifying manually the symbol in one of the .lib files with a binaray editor (e.g. [PsPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/)).

Just change `_deflate_copyright` into e.g. `_deflate_copyrigXX`. The characters must not be *removed* but they must be *replaced*.

Don't replace the characters at the *start* of the symbol name (e.g. replacing `_deflate_copyright` by `_Xeflate_copyright` as this will confuse the linker's internal search algorithm.